# eclipse workspace continuos refresh

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I installed eclipse 4.8 on Debian 9.4.
Every time I pass the mouse cursor, or when I try to write the code, on the workspace I have an annoying and continuous refresh of the working area. I can not work, I can not clearly see what I write. I tried, unnecessarily, on the web if someone else had had and solved the same problem. Can someone help me to solve this trivial but unfortunately essential problem?
Thank you.
P.S. Please watch the attached video.

https://youtu.be/dKc0SH_b3wc

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling eclipse or resetting your settings (make an backup before probably).

Comment: I installed eclipse on another pc with debian 9.4 and I have the same problems.

Comment: Do you have you have Window->Preferences->General->Workspace: "Refresh using native hooks or polling" active?

Comment: Yes, I have already set this configuration in preference.